# Change text overflow in jasper reports chart

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

It seems that the text is to long to be displayed at the bottom... that's ok but it would be nice if the text wasn't cut at the beginning and not at the end.
I can't find the spot where to do it. Is it even possible?

[image: Chart]

Comment: it is a bar chart

Comment: Is it belongs to highcharts (pro components) or just a simple bar chart?